# How to add a QR code to an image automatically

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code

I am developing an image management app for IOS. User in this case takes an picture and the image is stored in content store (Not on device). If user wants to save the image, the image is uploaded to cloud along with its HASH and geo info. I want to add a QR code to the image in cloud which will have its HASH and Geo info stored in it.

Whats the best way to implement this module.

There is a manual process on how to accomplish this here-https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-add-qr-codes-to-your-photos/# . I want to automate it for the images.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You need to generate a QR code containing *some* information, create an image from that and then merge the original image and the qr image, that sounds pretty straight forward for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using Core Image. It has a QR code generator filter, as well as image compositing filters. You should be able to find a tutorial on generating QR codes using a CI filter, and another one on compositing images together. It should be straightforward to combine those 2 steps.